# How to check the new imagename generated doesn't exists to prevent overriding?

Tags: java

Before Storing a file i am checking if the file name already exists (to prevent overriding)

For this i am using the following code

The issue with the below code is that there is no guarantee that newimage generated does not already exist.

```
public static String checkIfFileExists(String image_name,String from) throws IOException
        {
        String newimage = "";
        String path="";
        Properties props_load = Utility.getProperties();
       path = props_load.getProperty("videopath"); 
        File file =  new File(path+image_name);
        if (file.exists())  // **if file name already exists**
        { 
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\.(.*?)").matcher(image_name);
        if (matcher.matches()) {  // <== test input filename is OK?
        newimage = String.format("%s_%d.%s", matcher.group(1), randomInt, matcher.group(2));
        }
        }
        else
        {
        newimage = image_name;
        }
        return newimage;
        }
```

Comment: use createNewFile https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()

Comment: How to check the new file doesn't exist as well? Use `File.exists()` again (note that `new File(path)` doesn't create a file but just handle so unless you actually write to that file nothing gets created on the filesystem). How to prevent name clashes or at least reduce them? Use `UUID`.

Comment: All of the above and after changing the name, you'll have to retest with the new name.

Comment: Could you not simply loop over your _newImage_ name to retry if it exists or not? Add a counter to the mix to prevent deathloops. You can even write a recursive call for that task to make it look fancy

Comment: "You can even write a recursive call for that task" @Nikolas why in the world would you *want* to do that?

Comment: @fildor as he said, to make it look fancy. That's of course terrible reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createNewFile, thats all!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        System.out.println(checkIfFileExists("test.png",""));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String checkIfFileExists(String image_name,String from) throws IOException
    {
    String newimage = "test.png";
    String path="D:/";
    //Properties props_load = Utility.getProperties();
    path = "D:/";//props_load.getProperty("videopath"); 
    File file =  new File(path+image_name);
    if (!file.createNewFile())  // **if file name already exists**
    { 
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\.(.*?)").matcher(image_name);
    if (matcher.matches()) {  // <== test input filename is OK?
    newimage = String.format("%s_%d.%s", matcher.group(1), randomInt, matcher.group(2));
    }
    }
    else
    {
    newimage = image_name;
    }
    return newimage;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why not use File#createNewFile() ?

It's there to only create a file if one doesn't yet exist with the given name.
Using it in a loop and changing the filename inside the loop until the creation succeeds should do the trick.
Something like

```html
boolean created = false;
File file;
while (!created) {
  file = new File(randomfilename);
  created = file.createNewFile();
}

// write file
```